# What is the equivalent of setting the variation to 0 (FL Studio) in Logic Pro X

Tags: logic-pro, audio, audio-editing

My goal is to make the vocals sound super unnatural. The vocals were produced by google translate and I would like to go directly from a note to the next, no sliding or anything. Here is a screenshot of some of the audio. I need the white line (the note actually being made) to always be the note I programmed in. So no matter what the original sounded like, it will sing the melody exactly. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Your request reminds me of Autotune, which will snap all the vocals to the closest (probably A440 12-TET) notes.

Comment: Your title really confused me. I didn't know what you were asking until I read the body of the question. [I still don't understand the title, even after that] +1 for Autotune, btw [or Waves Tune, same but different]